# How to prevent Audacious to control overall system sound?

Tags: 14.04, sound, audacious

When I mute sound in Audacious it mutes sound on whole system.
For example if I play music in Audacious and on Youtube at the same time , muting sound in Audacious will mute Youtube as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the output plug-in. Go to **File**  - **Preferences** - **Audio**:

(In my case changing from Alsa Output to PulseAudio Output solved the problem)

[image]